# PHP including the wrong file (twice)

Tags: php, opcache

I have two sites on the same Apache installation

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2022-03-16T16:52:53
```

which are very similar. I have boiled down the problem to these three files:

```
<?php
    echo "I am One<br>";
    require_once('/var/www/one/htdocs/config.php');
    okay();

<?php
    echo "This is Config One<br>";
    require_once('/var/www/one/htdocs/functions.php');

<?php
    echo "This is Functions One<br>";
    function okay() {
        echo "Aaaand we are GO!<hr/>";
    }
    // Other 100K of templates and boilerplate. This might be relevant.
```

Test Site Two is identical, with Two instead of One.

The error is only occasional and difficult to reproduce. It manifests with the following apparently impossible error:

```
Fatal error: cannot redeclare okay() (previously declared in 
/var/www/two/htdocs/functions.php:3 in /var/www/one/htdocs/functions.php on line 3
```

Now, I fully agree that I can't declare okay() twice. Fact is that while in site One, **I never included anything from site Two**.

## Problem happens in "streaks"

From the logs (there is no full correlation with traffic on the sites; high traffic is required for the bug to manifest, but it's not enough, I got several high traffic periods where nothing happened), there is no immediately apparent rhyme or reason:

Bug# Date   Hour
2 Mar 16 14
9 Mar 17 11
2 Mar 18 09
1 Mar 22 10
24 Mar 22 11
1 Mar 22 18   Medium traffic, and yet problems - but only one
3 Mar 22 20
Mar 23: high traffic, no problems
4 Mar 24 10
11 Mar 24 12   High traffic at 14:00, problem appear at 15:00
22 Mar 24 15   Server restarted at 15:40...
5 Mar 24 16   ...problems reappear at 16:07
5 Mar 25 10
5 Mar 25 11
2 Mar 25 18
2 Mar 25 19
21 Mar 29 11

There's a preference for the 11:00 time frame for the bug to occur, but there's no obvious traffic or request pattern that stands out that's not, say, in the 13:00 time frame, when nothing ever happened.

Nothing ever happened on the weekend, but also nothing ever happened on a Monday. You'd think the bug needed some time to "mature" after a traffic lull, but that too cannot be (it happened after less than half an hour from Apache full restart, with a traffic level comparable to a Saturday).

## I don't think it is an `opcache` problem.

This kind of error is a common gotcha with `opcache` module, because it caches *names* and not the full paths, so if a "functions" file gets in the cache, the next one to include a different "functions" file sorts of gets it in the neck.

But I don't believe this is the reason, because:

- I had already set up properly opcache (or at least I think so):

  opcache.revalidate_path                   1
  opcache.use_cwd                           1
  opcache.file_cache_consistency_checks     1
- all my includes use the full path, which has no ambiguities

## OK, this is officially crazy.

Following @JensV's clever suggestion, I added a `function_exists()` test in `config.php`, *before* including the `functions.php` file. This actually caught out a **different** incarnation of the same bug, which I had missed.

```
if (function_exists('okay')) {
    dump $_SERVER, get_included_files() and a lot of other things
    to a bagonghi.txt file
}
// Okay, the function is not defined. Define it.
require_once('/var/www/one/htdocs/functions.php');
```

The *same* functions.php file (i.e., the one in site `one`) turned out to sometime result *already included*, *before* the `require_once` happened. But even better, this is the output of `get_included_files()`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /var/www/one/index.php
    [1] => /var/www/one/config.php
)
```

...the function `okay()` is defined, but the only file that defines it **has not yet been included**.

So, this looks very much like a bug in the PHP (module, at the very least), except that I'm usually chary of calling out "bug" in something that lots of people ought to have noticed before I did.

I am using Apache module for now, and I'm reasonably confident that switching to FPM would remove the issue (at the very least, I can run `one` and `two` under different pools).

But I'm at my wits' end to understand what is actually going on here.

Comment: _"because it caches names and not the full paths"_ if it is true, most sites will be broken.

Comment: @shingo they would be, but usually `use_cwd` is set to 1 ( https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.use-cwd )

Comment: `use_cwd` doesn't take effect for absolute path, and `require_once` needs to resolve the filename to full path to work. if you take a look at `opcache_get_status`, you'll find in most cases opcache caches the full path.

Comment: By your wording it seems that you are assuming this is an issue with opcache does that mean it works correctly when opcache is turned off?

Comment: @shingo I have modified the question to make it clearer that **I don't believe `opcache` is the culprit**. Actually, I had included it only to avoid people pointing out that it *could have been* the culprit :-)

Comment: You may want to add a declaration check before the function declaration and log everything about the request you are able to. Then you could figure out what request triggers this.

Comment: the code you posted is insufficient to help you, please post your apache configuration where you declare your sites. Probably the mistake is in config, the sites are executing all files, causing this redeclaration issue

Comment: If you were able to solve this problem, please add an answer and accept it. This helps others. First of all, the question will no longer be listed as unanswered. Also, it makes it easier for people who have a similar problem. (It is ok to write an update to the question as to what helped, but that can be done in addition to writing an answer, not instead of). Thanks.

Comment: "The incompatibility between the two modules is well documented." If so, please add a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## it was, of course, a module.

Just not `opcache` *alone*. It turns out that the machine had (mistakenly) still active several PHP debugging/development modules, among these, `runkit7`. I had not checked it when adding `opcache` for staging and profiling, and this carelessness quite properly came back to bit me on the tail.

Incompatibilities between the two modules [are known](https://github.com/runkit7/runkit7/issues/217).